# Toilet not flushing after clearing a clog

Tags: toilet, drain

My toilet was clogged recently and I opened it with a toilet auger, and now another problem came up, every time I'm flushing the water is coming up and filling the toilet for a few seconds and then its going down at regular speed.I took down the toilet and there is no water sitting in the drain but I still augered it with my 6 Ft. toilet auger also I'v cleaned all the holes inside the toilet with CLR as mentioned in answers on similar questions but nothing helped. All other fixtures including another toilet are working fine and this one was also everything ok till now.
Thanks

Comment: If the bowl is filling rapidly with flush water and still only draining to the normal level at a slow rate instead of "flushing", then you still have a clog.

Comment: @JPhi1618 - yes.  Just probably a smaller clog further down the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the answers. After trying all of them and it still did not work I went back and tryed pouring in a bucket water (I forgot about it before) and it flushed very smoothly so I guessed I have to focus on the water supply. I started with the CLR again and while working at the bottom at the jet stream I stuck my finger in as far as I could and... there is it, I felt a small corner of something soft, after little work and few more flushes it came out and its a baby wipe! probably went in while plunging the clog, (the cover was always in place so it did'nt go in thru the tank) and now its flushing wonder full.                         Thanks again for your times they are good information anyway.

Comment: You should mark this as the accepted answer (click the tick/check mark to the left)

Answer (score 4):

First, insure you're using **the correct plunger: a rubber one**, not the newfangled fluted plastic ones. And go absolutely nuts with it. The important part is the pull-back, to dislodge the clog (you don't just push on it). If it doesn't fight you pulling back, you didn't achieve suction; change your angle.

[image]

([source](http://www.lowes.com/pd_473773-255-7503600L_0__?productId=4777772))

[image]

> <sub>Your ideal sink plunger, on the left, & toilet plunger, on the right.</sub>

([source](http://greenathens.net/apartment-living-101/2013/2/20/to-wield-a-plunger))

My preference is the simple one on the left, it does everything. The 'flute' on the right always just ends up inside itself. Either of these are better than that first one though.

---

After that comes using **a real sewer rodder**. For which you might want to pull the toilet to avoid scratching or damaging it, assuming there's no other clean-outs to provide access.

[image]

([source](http://www.edsrental.com/rodder-hand-25))

If you're sure there's no other take-offs between the toilet and the clog, you can try a [Drain Cleaning Water Bladder](https://www.google.com/search?q=Drain%20Cleaning%20Water%20Bladder&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjDqenh-JPLAhXLaRQKHY1GBroQ_AUICCgC&biw=1024&bih=677) that uses a garden hose. But if there are other take-offs however, you're going to shoot water out of the sink drain. Generally, these are only used on the main line and only if it's a *soft* clog. It's not going to help you if you have a [kid's toy stuck in there](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/76913/need-help-with-toilet-not-draining).

[image]

Comment: +1 but note that the black "toilet plunger" often leaves some pretty harsh marks on the toilet.  Nothing that can't be rubbed out... but not an area you want to rub something out...

Answer (score 0):

Great job actually. But, get the auger again & follow a flush with it. And, also flush again & again as you feed & retract the auger. Just snake the toilet's 2-feet.

The clog is still flapping down during the flush & you should be able to catch it & clear it. You can also try a garden hose for something larger & turn its water on. If you have a very short stub nose for the hose you can run that too for a stronger blast.

If it's a toilet that uses 2-gallons or less, then single flushing #2's is the problem. Whether it's sold as a "Dual Flush" or not, they all are. For #2's hold the handle down until the bowl is clear & do a 2nd flush the same way.

Having a lower & smaller wet-spot in the bowl lets most of the remaining path to dry out & that dryness will catch & even collect tissues.